# Как написать правильно, чтобы был понятен смысл предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, смысл

К примеру: «на ногах его грязь».
Как обозначить так, чтобы было понятно, что грязь на его ногах, а не на ногах грязь, принадлежащая ему.

Answer (score 1):

Можно отделить тире:

- На ногах его — грязь. (Сравните: *На ногах — его грязь.*)

Или переставить слова так, чтобы не было двусмысленности:

- На его ногах грязь.

Comment: *На его ногах грязь.* Такая перестановка (без соответствующего контекста) все равно не дает однозначного понимания — чья же это грязь. Сравните: *На его руках кровь*. Его собственная, или кого-то другого, или в переносном смысле (совершить убийство или быть причастным к убийству)?

Comment: Не знаю, есть ли такое в лингвистике, но я использую оборот "по умолчанию". Например, кивнуть *по умолчанию* можно только головой, поэтому фраза "Он кивнул головой" — плеоназм. Но если мы описываем инопланетянина, который может кивать головой, хвостом и хребтом, то выражение "Он кивнул головой" будет необходимым уточнением. Так и с грязью. Она *по умолчанию* — просто грязь. А вот если требуется уточнить, чья она, тогда уже следует соответствующим образом выстраивать предложение.

Comment: Так в именно в этом и есть смысл вопроса.

Comment: Я полагаю, *по умолчанию* грязь ничья. Поэтому мой вариант "На его ногах грязь" и счёл в рамках заданного вопроса однозначным.

Answer (score 1):

Можно (и удобно, если нет возможности перестроить предложение) поставить тире, которое называется [интонационным](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94).

> **1.** Тире ставится для указания места ***разделения*** простого предложения на ***словесные группы***, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить ***смысловые отношения*** между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен. Ср.:
> *Ходить — долго не мог* (‘лишен был возможности передвигаться в течение длительного периода, например после тяжелой болезни’); *Ходить долго — не мог* (‘не мог заниматься длительной ходьбой’)...

**На ногах — его грязь**. На его ногах находится его же грязь.
**На ногах его — грязь**. На его ногах находится какая-то (неизвестно чья) грязь.

Вдруг, очнувшись, вспомнил Юлиан, что он ― в глубине Персии, что он ― римский император, что *на руках его ― шестьдесят тысяч солдат*, что богов нет, что он опрокинул жертвенник, кощунствуя. [Д. С. Мережковский. Смерть богов. Юлиан Отступник (1895)]

*На плечах его ― двухметровый перш* с вершинной площадкой, на которую взгромождается партнер с таким же точно першем... [Надежда на чертову дюжину // «Культура», 2002.04.08]
[Перш](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88)

Comment: Точно -- интонационное. А у меня в голове всё крутилось "смысловое, смысловое" :)

Comment: Спасибо за оценку (если она, конечно, ваша). И — просто для удобства: тире (длинное) — Alt + 0151; тире короткое (среднее) — Alt + 0150.

Comment: Спасибо. Я привык, что в ВК и у меня в ворде два дефиса конвертируются в длинное тире, по привычке так пишу. Теперь буду использовать альт-код.